# WPF DataGrid, in a Binding in a ColumnTemplate access a Element outside of the DataGrid

Tags: wpf, templates, data-binding, datagrid, datacontext

I'd like to access a Object from my UserControl from within the Datgrids ColumnTemplate.

This doesn't work. Now I've read it's because of the Datacontext.

I found this Example, which should fix this: http://blog.errorok.com/2010/09/09/212/

But the Event: ColumnDataContextChanged is never called in my Project!

here's a part of my XAML:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Database-Fieldtype" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="False" SortMemberPath="DatabaseFieldType">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DatabaseFieldType}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ConfigurationTool:EditProtocolDatasets}}, Path=grdDatasets.SelectedItem.Storage.DatabaseFieldTypes}" 
                      SelectedItem="{Binding DatabaseFieldType}"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="179" Padding="0" Margin="0">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>

        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

ConfigurationTool:EditProtocolDatasets is my UserControl, grdDatasets is another Datagrid, to which SelectedItem I'd like to bind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm going to suggest a completely different direction than my first one.  My guess is that you have the ItemsSource for grdDatasets bound to something.

For the item that's going to act as your datacontext for the control, make sure it has the following characteristics, or at least a comparable structure:

```
public class ListOfDataSets : DependencyObject
{
  public IEnumerable<DataSetOption> Items
  {
    get
    {
      ...Whatever you normally use to get your DataSetOptions...
    }
  }

  public DataSetOption SelectedItem
  {
    get { return (DataSetOption)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(DataSetOption), typeof(ListOfDataSets), new PropertyMetadata(null));

}
```

The key here is that you have one property that is a list of your choices, and another property that represents one of those items.

Then, in your XAML, your control can have the following structure:

```
<UserControl>
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <ConfigurationTool:ListOfDatasets x:Key=DataSetOptions />
  </UserControl.Resources>
  <StackPanel Name="LayoutRoot">
    <DataGrid Name="grdDatasets" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataSetOptions}, Path=Items}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataSetOptions}, Path=SelectedItem}"
        ...
    </DataGrid>
...
    <DataGrid Name="OtherDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding OtherSource}">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
    ...
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Database-Fieldtype" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="False" SortMemberPath="DatabaseFieldType">
                     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                             <TextBlock Text="{Binding DatabaseFieldType}" />
                         </DataTemplate>
                     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate> 
                        <DataTemplate>
                             <ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource DataSetOptions}, Path=SelectedItem.Storage.DatabaseFieldTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding DatabaseFieldType, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="179" Padding="0" Margin="0">
                                 <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                     <DataTemplate>
                                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                     </DataTemplate>
                                 </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                             </ComboBox>
                              </DataTemplate>
                     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      </Datagrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

I actually tried this structure out, and the databinding works fine.  If the DataSetOptions change a lot, though, this solution may not work, unless you're using MVVM, and the ViewModel is good at tracking what options are available, and presents them properly to the View.

Hopefully this makes sense.  I actually tried this one before answering.

I was not correct with my original answer, and overestimated the capabilities of RelativeSource before I experimented with it.

---Original text below---

I think I can help, but I need a few more details.  For now I'm just going to work off assumptions.

Assumption 1: You're in a WPF UserControl with a DataGrid that has a defined ItemsSource.
Assumption 2: The UserControl has another element that you want a column within your DataGrid to have access to.

If these two assumptions are correct, it is a much better problem to have in WPF than in Silverlight.

Each row in your DataGrid is going to be working from within a DataContext that consists of the Item for that row.  But, you can reach outside of the cell's (or any) DataContext with a RelativeSource.

So, if you wanted to go up the Visual Tree to get to your control's Width, you would use:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MyUserControl}}, Path=Width}
```

This will trace upward in the Visual Tree until an object of type "MyUserControl" is found, at which point it will grab the "Width" property and bind to it.

The Path doesn't have to be only one item deep, either.  You can run up an down your visual tree as required.  As this gets more complex, though, your code is going to be more fragile.

If this isn't correct, please post your XAML (or something similar) and say so, and I'll spin up a test environment and edit my post.

Comment: You are right, with both of your assumptions!
But why does the code with the DataContexes not work?

I also tryed it with RelativeSoure, but my problem is, that i want not search for the type of a control, i want to Find a Control by the Name!

I tryed it now so:

ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ConfigurationTool:EditProtocolDatasets}}, Path=grdDatasets.SelectedItem.Storage.DatabaseFieldTypes}"

but this does not work, because grdDatasets is no property (it's a control!)

Comment: I will try your new Solution out, but i think it would work!

But do you have any Idea why the Solution in http://blog.errorok.com/2010/09/09/212/ does not work?

Comment: I really don't.  I've only worked with custom attached properties once or twice at this point, and without really diving into his solution, I couldn't really tell you.  If I get a spare couple hours or stumble across a reason, I'll let you know.

Comment: I now tryed it another way:

I added a helper Property:
        public DataGrid GetGrdDatsetsObject { get { return grdDatasets; } }

and tryed the Binding so:
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ConfigurationTool:EditProtocolDatasets}}, Path=GetGrdDatsetsObject}

I got no Binding error, but the List is empty!

Comment: Try it with `Path=GetGrdDatSetsObject.SelectedItem` maybe?

Comment: Ok, it now works with the Helper Property....  I had the Binding wrong!
But thanks...